# VS2013 Qt Addin - adding a new form

Tags: forms, qt

I'm using VS2013 with Qt Addin 1.2.4. The Add -> New Item box doesn't show any Qt  options. So can anyone explain how to get a new form into the project together with all the necessary commands to compile it properly?

Thanks

alan

Comment: Hi! From where can I download this addin? I was just looking for it yesterday, but there is no download link on the Qt website.

Comment: Go to the downloads page http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/ and at the bottom of the page is a line "Not the download package you need? View All Downloads". Click on the "View All Downloads" link and that will take you to a page with all the other downloads in, including the add-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Project` -> `Add Class` and there you'll have `Qt5 Classes` and inside `Qt5GuiClass` (that adds the form and it's corresponding .h and .cpp files)